# React application

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi I am totally new to the frontend stuff and have been learning react and javascript and would like your suggestion.

I have been writing a simple application and have a state machine and its control flow. On the app I have states such as Init, Idle, Connected and Finish. So depending on the state I call different render() function.

```
class StateMachine extends Component {
  state = {
    current: States.INIT,
...

  async transition(to: any) {
    this.setState({ current: to }); 
  }
...
 render() { 
    switch (this.state.current) {
      case States.INIT: 
        return this.renderInit();
      case States.IDLE:
        return this.renderIdle();
....
```

If I were to write it in python or C++ I would totally move UI component away from the control flow (eg. write the UI in a different file and bind it). But with react with this "component" idea it seems best to have the UI component in the same file. Maybe I should call another Component from this render() ? Do you have any suggestion ?

Thanks,

Comment: If you ask "the right way", you will see 10 different solutions

Comment: Well in general I would agree with @meine. However consider that normally your state machine will move towards the core of your app's logic. The bigger the scale, the more likely your state machine will be as agnostic towards UI elements as possible. So I would vote for separating UI components from the state machine.